# Ведь(,) согласно

Tags: пунктуация, частицы

> **Ведь(,) согласно...**

Где-то запятую ставят, где-то — нет! Как понять, ставить или не ставить?

**Некоторые примеры из Нацкорпуса:**

Ведь, согласно учебникам, устойчивой и серьезной нематериальной мотивацией являются ценности компании?

Ведь согласно протоколу государственного визита, Горбачев должен был возложить венок к памятнику народным героям в центре площади Тяньаньмэнь.

Ведь, согласно этой теории, у каждой частицы должны быть «двойники», которые отличаются от нее по какому-нибудь параметру.

Ведь согласно теории, наша Вселенная около 20 млрд. лет назад образовалась в результате Большого Взрыва.

Comment: Желаете получить конкретный ответ, — приводите фразу без сокращений.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Если поставить запятую, то частица "ведь" будет относиться к предложению, а если не ставить, то к обособленному обстоятельственному обороту. В принципе оба варианта возможны, но **как сделать выбор?**
2. Постановка запятой зависит от структуры предложения и от желания автора подчеркнуть значимость оборота. В этом случае оборот произносится с ударением и с особой вставочной интонацией, что способствует его выделению.

Сравним **два варианта:**

***Ведь согласно протоколу государственного визИта**, Горбачев должен был возложить венок к памятнику народным героям в центре площади Тяньаньмэнь.*

*Ведь, **согласно этой теОрии,** у каждой частицы должны быть «двойники», которые отличаются от нее по какому-нибудь параметру.*

3. Также частица чаще включается в **нераспространенные** обороты:

***Ведь согласно теОрии**, наша Вселенная около 20 млрд. лет назад образовалась в результате Большого Взрыва.*

Comment: Как сделать выбор? Если редактируете чужой текст, то принимаете решение (на базе кругозора и погружения в материал). Если вы автор, то знаете наперёд — точно перед тем, как частица появилась на бумаге, частью чего она  является. И это опять не выбор.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо за ваше мнение , и давайте на этом закончим дискуссию.  Вот последнее, что я вам скажу.  В приведенных примерах все обороты обособлены, поэтому вопрос был не об их обособлении., а только по частице ВЕДЬ: включать ее в обособленный оборот или нет. Так что правило о факультативном обособлении, которое вы приводите в ответе, — это вообще не тема этого вопроса.

Comment: Или обоблены криво, что похоже на ошибку, на пропуск, на что намекать не стал. О выборе прочитав, так и забыли. Расходимся.

Answer (score 0):

Ведь — усилительная частица — предваряет фразу с дополнительной информацией, содержащей подтверждение ранее сказанному. Частица не отделяется от смысловой части и смысла не изменяет.

О пунктуации в примерах: вводные слова, требующие обособления, не во всех случаях обособлены. Подобные нераспространенные обороты, стоящие в начале или в конце предложения, обычно не обособляются, и можно говорить о факультативности обособления:

> Обороты со следующими предлогами могут обособляться или не
> обособляться: *благодаря, ввиду, в зависимости от, в нарушение, во
> избежание, во исполнение, в отличие от, вплоть до, в противовес, в
> противоположность, в связи с, в силу, вследствие, в случае, в
> соответствии с, за вычетом, за недостаточностью, за неимением, за
> отсутствием, назло, на основании, наперекор, наравне с, наряду с, на
> случай, под видом, подобно, под  предлогом, по истечении, по мере, по
> меркам, по праву, по причине, по случаю, по условиям, при наличии,
> при условии, против (в знач. «вопреки»), сверх (в знач. «кроме,
> помимо») согласно, соответственно*.

Отсутствие запятых во 2 и 4-м примерах означает включение частицы в обстоятельственный оборот, что правилами не регламентируется.

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что частица ВЕДЬ не может включаться в обстоятельственный оборот?  У вас есть информация о том,, что это запрещается? Практика письма показывает, что такой вариант возможен.

Comment: Где слово *запрещается*? Я пишу, что нет регламента.

Comment: Значит, так можно писать, все варианты верны? Тогда  следует объяснить, как выбрать подходящий вариант, то есть чем они отличаются. Об этом же был вопрос: "Как понять, ставить или не ставить?"

Comment: О выборе подходящего варианта не в курсе, но да, все варианты верны: их можно не править. А можно править. Они же из сети, что толку? Факультативность обособления это и предполагает. Об отличии — в последней фразе.

Comment: По вашему ответу сложно принять решение. Ответ можно понять так: пишите как вам нравится, у Розенталя тема частицы "ведь" для таких случаев не рассмотрена. Или поищите ответ где-нибудь еще, У Грамоты. ру можно, например, спросить.

Comment: Решение по какой фразе принять? Её нет. Вопрос Катперкат, очевидно, не был подготовленным, иначе бы здесь была дана проблемная фраза.

Comment: Дело не в конкретной фразе.  Выбор правильного варианта важен для пользователей, так как при разной пунктуации могут разные СМЫСЛОВЫЕ оттенки. Возьмите фразу: (1) «Ведь согласно теории, наша Вселенная  образовалась в результате Большого Взрыва».  Здесь дана  информация с указанием на  источник.  (2) «Ведь, согласно теОрии, наша Вселенная образовалась в результате Большого Взрыва, но не все современные фАкты свидетельствуют об этом». Здесь оборот особо подчеркнут и логически выделено противопоставление.

Comment: Понятие *факультативно* разве отбрасывает работу со смыслами? Оно и предполагает множественность оттенков. Достаточно было сказанного в ответе, чтобы понять: нет фразы, сняв кальку с которой, будет допустимо использовать её бездумно.

Comment: Понятие "факультативно" никаким образом не указывает, как "работать со смыслами" и выбирать нужный вариант. Этот вопрос вообще не так прост, учитывая значение частицы "ведь", но это длинный разговор. Писатели разбираются с факультативностью, исходя из чувства языка, другим же пользователем нужны хотя бы какие-то ориентиры. Вы же им не предложили ничего конкретного. Это та же тема, когда в ответе говорится: здесь по правилам пишется двоеточие, но его можно заменить тире, хотя запятая тоже допускается. Вот так иногда выглядит факультативность.